# Excel 2010 - getting a find - array to properly parse cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an array of data I'm looking for. Let's say they're the months of the year, from Jan to December. Call it array Months. In A1 to A400 I have text that's been entered. It looks like blahblahJanblah, or blahblahblah (no month). In B1 to B400 I'd like to get a flag (let's call it yes or no) that says if there is a month hiding in A1 or not. I've tried arrays, index match, find, and more to little success. Most promising was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587464/excel-find-cells-from-range-where-search-value-is-within-the-cell , but that didn't work.

I'm using excel 2010.

I have not tried to use a macro, but I'd be willing to try

Edits: replaced find with search, and doing a regular find on a test sample is generating results, it's just failing in an array. Additionally the array formula fails to slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this formula in B1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Months,A1)))
```

And copy down.

Comment: It works! For some reason my negatives are 231 and my positives are 232